# dlltool fails with python27.def file

Tags: python, cross-compiling, swig, extension-modules

I want to create the libpython27.a from python27.dll (C:Windows/SysWOW64)

I linux:

```
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/dlltool  -A --dllname python27.dll --def python27.def --output-lib libpython27.a
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/dlltool: Syntax error in def file python27.def:11
```

Running dlltool with -v, I get:

```
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/dlltool: Using file: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/as
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/dlltool: Processing def file: python27.def
��/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/dlltool: Syntax error in def file python27.def:11
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/dlltool: Processed def file
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/dlltool: Processing definitions
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/dlltool: Processed definitions
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/dlltool: Creating library file: libpython27.a
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/dlltool: run: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/as   -o dlumbh.o dlumbh.s
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/dlltool: run: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/as   -o dlumbt.o dlumbt.s
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/dlltool: Created lib file
```

As you can see, I got the syntax error for python27.def file, but libpython27.a is build.

I created python27.def as follow: (in Windows)

- got pexports-0.47-mingw32-bin.tar.xz (suppouse to support 32 and 64 bit)
- run pexports.exe -v .\python27.dll > python27.def

Content of python27.def:

```
; .text   : RVA: 00001000, File offset: 00000400
; .rdata  : RVA: 000e7000, File offset: 000e6000
; .data   : RVA: 001b9000, File offset: 001b7e00
; .rsrc   : RVA: 00214000, File offset: 00209200
; .reloc  : RVA: 00215000, File offset: 00209a00
; Reading exports from section: .rdata
; Export table: python27.dll
; Ordinal base: 1
; Ordinal table RVA: 001b3300
; Name table RVA: 01b22b4
; Export address table RVA: 001b1268
LIBRARY python27.dll
EXPORTS
PyAST_Compile ; .text ; RVA 000c1a03
PyAST_FromNode ; .text ; RVA 000b394f
PyArena_AddPyObject ; .text ; RVA 000d4279
PyArena_Free ; .text ; RVA 000d4211
PyArena_Malloc ; .text ; RVA 000d424f
PyArena_New ; .text ; RVA 000d41bd
PyArg_Parse ; .text ; RVA 000cb1d6
PyArg_ParseTuple ; .text ; RVA 000cb218
PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords ; .text ; RVA 000ccb89
PyArg_UnpackTuple ; .text ; RVA 000cd191
PyArg_VaParse ; .text ; RVA 000cb25a
PyArg_VaParseTupleAndKeywords ; .text ; RVA 000ccc5c
PyBaseObject_Type DATA ; .data ; RVA 001d4728
PyBaseString_Type DATA ; .data ; RVA 001d8058
PyBool_FromLong ; .text ; RVA 00065ad7
PyBool_Type DATA ; .data ; RVA 001e6470
PyBuffer_FillContiguousStrides ; .text ; RVA 000631b8
PyBuffer_FillInfo ; .text ; RVA 0006320a
PyBuffer_FromContiguous ; .text ; RVA 00062f13
PyBuffer_FromMemory ; .text ; RVA 00065e2a
PyBuffer_FromObject ; .text ; RVA 00065dac
...
...
```

Is there a problem with my procces to create python27.def?

Note: There is a libpython27.a under but I read some comments that it doesn't work to link against to cross-compile a python extension module in linux.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you've solved it now, but you might be interested in a fairly long writeup I did a while back: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32413756/168175

Comment: Thank you, Flexo. I found your writeup quite useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I installed gendef (from win-builds) and created the python27.def

```
.\gendef.exe C:\Windows\SysWOW64\python27.dll
```

Then, in Linux, I run dlltool successfully to create the libpython27.a:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-dlltool -A --dllname python27.dll --def python27.def --output-lib libpython27.a
```

size of libpython27.a (gendef): **774580**

size of libpython27.a (failed with pexports): 1470

[win-builds](http://win-builds.org/doku.php/download_and_installation_from_windows)